# How to intercept "Stop" mediaObjects intent in Google Action

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have made an action that plays long mediaObjects (mp3). The problem here is that when the user says "Stop" or "cancel", the mp3 stops, but the action doesn't quit nor responds anything. So the user may think that the action is closed while it is not. So basically in order to quit you must say "Stop" two times, the first time the MP3 actually stops, and the second time you trigger the "close action" intent.

What can I do to close the action after the first stop? So it basically stops the mp3 and say good bye to the user and quits.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug with the MediaResponse.